# Unable to throw error Message

Tags: php, html, mysql

registration_form

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
   <head>
    <title>Register</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    Name: 
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br/> <br/>
    Username: 
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br/> <br/>
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <br/> <br/>

    Email: 
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <br/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>
</body>
    </html>
  <?php
 require('connect.php');
  require('validation.php');
    $name = $_POST['name'];
  $username = $_POST['username'];
       $password = $_POST['password'];

  $email = $_POST['email'];

     if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
       if($query = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users 
     (`id`,`name`,`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES ('','".$name."', 
      '".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')")){
          echo "Success";
      }else{
         echo "Failure" . mysqli_error($connect);
         }
           }
   ?>
```

validation.php

```
     <?php
      // define variables and set to empty values
      $nameErr = $emailErr = $userErr = $passwordErr = "";
      $name =  $email = $username =$password = "";


       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
         $nameErr = "Name is required";
       } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
       }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
         $emailErr = "Email is required";
         } else {
       $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
         // check if e-mail address is well-formed
         if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
           $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
         }
         }

        if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
       $userErr = "Username is required";
       } else {
        $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
          }

        if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
         $passwordErr = "Password is required";
       } else {
       $password= test_input($_POST["password"]);
          }

     }

      function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
      }
        ?>
```

connect.php

```
    <?php
     $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","php_forum") 
    or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connect)); 
       ?>
```

I'm developing a simple Registration from with four inputs i.e., Name, username, password, email.when the user fills out the form and click submit button then all the filled data should go n save in data base which is working fine in my case, but when the user wont fill any data and if user simply clicks a submit button then error message should be shown like "ALL FIELDS ARE NECESSARY", but where in my case even if i click submit button without entering any values the mesage i'm getting as success and all the null values are getting stored in the data base which should not happen, my output should be if i fill the forms n click submit button then all the data should be stored in database and if i click submit button without filling out any value then error should throw that "all field to be filled" and no null value should be stored in data base, please can any one guide me what changes i should do so that to get my desired output.

Comment: for a start dont ever store plain text passwords.

Comment: my actual problem is not that

Comment: ok i will try to fix

Comment: So, why don't you check for the errors before inserting? There is no code involved to blocking the insertion if an error occured...

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
require('validation.php');
```

setting and checking alot of variables e.g.

```
 $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
 $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
```

come back from require and overwrite  $name with original posted values and do nothing with $nameErr

```
 $name = $_POST['name'];
```

check the errors after the require

e.g.

```
require('validation.php');
$lsError = $nameErr . $emailErr . $userErr . $passwordErr;
if(trim($lsError) != '') {
    echo $lsError ."<BR>";
    echo "ALL FIELDS ARE NECESSARY";
}
else {
   //rest of your insert
}
```